# The std::filesystem current_path returns the root one

Tags: c++, linux, docker, emscripten, emcc

I just wanna to print the current path and its content, via `std::filesystem::path::current_path` (the compiler is `emcc` [this one](https://emscripten.org/)). Some code below:

```cpp
//... some stuff ...
namespace fs = 
#if defined(_MSC_VER) || defined(_WIN32) 
  std::filesystem;
#else
  std::__fs::filesystem;
#endif
//... some stuff ...
cfg::Config::Config() { this->Path = fs::current_path(); }

void cfg::Config::getPath()
{
    for (auto &p : fs::directory_iterator(this->Path)) std::cout << p.path() << '\n';
}
```

And for windows it works fine, the output looks like:

```
...
"D:\\GitHub\\Emscripten_OpenGL\\build\\cmake_install.cmake"
"D:\\GitHub\\Emscripten_OpenGL\\build\\Debug"
"D:\\GitHub\\Emscripten_OpenGL\\build\\Emscripten_Graphics.dir"
"D:\\GitHub\\Emscripten_OpenGL\\build\\Emscripten_Graphics.sln"
"D:\\GitHub\\Emscripten_OpenGL\\build\\Emscripten_Graphics.vcxproj"
"D:\\GitHub\\Emscripten_OpenGL\\build\\Emscripten_Graphics.vcxproj.filters"
"D:\\GitHub\\Emscripten_OpenGL\\build\\Emscripten_Graphics.vcxproj.user"
...
```

However, whether for Linux subsystem or for docker container with Ubuntu image it just prints the root directory:

```
application_1  | [100%] Built target Emscripten_Graphics
application_1  | make: make
application_1  | "/tmp"
application_1  | "/home"
application_1  | "/dev"
application_1  | "/proc"
```

May be I something missed apropos the Linux's `std::filesystem`?

Comment: `std::__fs::filesystem;`  you should not use any symbol starting with double underscore. Can you explain way you are doing that? Did you forgot to enable C++17 on Linux?

Comment: Wha version of `GCC` are you using? Current versions have `std::filesystem` and older versions have `std::experimental::filesystem`. I've never seen `std::__fs::filesystem` though.

Comment: @Marek R yep, I do that because in other way it raises an exception (`std::filesystem` not found and the system recommends to use this one). I'm using `emcc` [compiler](https://emscripten.org/).

Comment: Do you understand the concept of a working directory? What working directory do you expect your Docker program to run in? Did you specify any [WORKDIR](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir) in the Dockerfile?

Comment: @rustyx I did specify. It should be something like `app/build/...`. As I currently comprehend it's occurring because of the compiler.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure. How do you know your Dockerfile is correct? Did you check that the program actually starts in the specified directory?

Comment: @rustyx In other way it might not be able to find `CMakeLists.txt` in the WORKDIR. And if even the Dockerfile is wrong, I've tried to do the same manually in the linux subsystem the output the same.

Comment: if you run compiled with `emcc` version - it "mounts" virtual filesystem where everything starts from root and it is probably the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, so it's may be useful to others. Thanks to [@Sugar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1856291/sugar) I dug in the [Emscripten Filesystem API](https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/Filesystem-API.html). The emscripten creates its own virtual filesystem and uploading there files used in c++ code. According to [this issue](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/5237) the way to fix it is to add the `-s NODERAWFS=1` as flag, whilst compile.